# How to edit imported obj material easily?

Tags: materials, objects, import

I imported some obj from sketch up to Blender,
as you can see the white part should be other materials,
but whenever i want to select it, it is very hard for me to select only the object, as you can see the model has many faces, if i use select similar material, it will select other obj i dont want to edit. Please teach me how to assign material to this object easily, thanks.[image]

Comment: You cab use the L key to select each of those loops. In Edit mode, hover your mouse over 1 or the vertices/edges/faces of one of the loops then hit the L key. This will selct all the geometry of that loop. Then move your mouse over the next loop and use the L key again to select all of it. Repeat for any other parts you want to include then assign the material to them.

Comment: THank you very much! it save me alot of time!